# Get results from a MySQL database recursively

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

Consider the following:

`Table - id, parentid`

What I'd like to do, is I'd like to pull all the children (not only direct children, but all of them, i.e. children of children of children etc.) of a specific parent.

So let's say the table contains the following row: `(2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 4)`

Then for parentid = 1, the table would return ids 2, 3, 4 AND 5.

Is this possible?

If not (and I guess it's indeed not possible), what are my options?

I really don't want to use dozens of queries...

P.S. I can't change the database structure.

Also, as there might be hundreds of thousands of records in the table, I can pull them all and do the whole thing using PHP instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
$parentId = 1; // the parent id
$arrAllChild = Array(); // array that will store all children
while (true) {
    $arrChild = Array(); // array for storing children in this iteration
    $q = 'SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `parentid` IN (' . $parentId . ')';
    $rs = mysql_query ($q);
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
        $arrChild[] = $r['id'];
        $arrAllChild[] = $r['id'];
    }
    if (empty($arrChild)) { // break if no more children found
        break;
    }
    $parentId = implode(',', $arrChild); // generate comma-separated string of all children and execute the query again
}
print_r($arrAllChild);
```

You may as well use recursion to do so but I think the above will need fewer iterations.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT** - I forgot to mention that you can as well implement the same logic in a MySQL stored procedure except that you cant use Arrays. The above example is implemented in PHP as you might have already guessed

Answer (score 0):

not in one step.

I have done recursive queries in MySQL using PHP... looping through one level, collecting the data, modifying the query to use the results brought back in the last iteration, running the query again, etc.

Mysql is not very friendly for this sort of thing.  MSSQL, Oracle, or PostgreSQL support it in singular query format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query I wrote just now for a similar problem:

```
select if(e.id is not null, e.id, if(d.id is not null, d.id, if(c.id is not null, c.id, if(b.id is not null, b.id, a.id)))) as ID
from groups a
left join groups b on b.parent = a.id
left join groups c on c.parent = b.id
left join groups d on d.parent = c.id
left join groups e on e.parent = d.id
where a.parent = SOMETOPLEVELPARENTIDHERE;
```

This approach does have a fixed depth limit. I know from my own data that it happens to span at most five levels of depth. If the depth is fairly stable you can accommodate some growth by simply adding more left joins. Also, not sure how the query will perform with hundreds of thousands of records.